# How to analyze $\sup_{x>0}|e^xf(x)| < \infty$ and $\sup_{n\in\mathbb{N}} |f^{(n)}(0)|< \infty$?

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, power-series

> Suppose that
>   $$f(x)=1+\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n \frac{x^n}{n!}\ \ \forall \ x\in \mathbb{R}$$
>   where $\sup_{x>0}\left|e^xf(x)\right| < \infty$ and $\sup_{n\in\mathbb{N}} |a_n|< \infty$.
>
> Prove that $a_n = (-1)^n$ , $\forall n\in \mathbb{N}$

It seems amazing to me. What we need to prove is $f(x)=e^{-x}$. It seems insufficient to prove this strong conclusion, but actually it is true and all the "counterexamples" I found were wrong.

**My attempt**

Put $g(x)=e^x f(x)$.
$$\left|g^{(n)}(0)\right|=\left|\sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k} f^{(k)}(0)\right|\le 2^n\sup_{n\in\mathbb{N}} |a_n|  $$
Put $h(x)=g(\frac{x}{2})$. Thus 
$$h^{(n)}(0)=\frac{1}{2^n}g(0) \le \sup_{n\in\mathbb{N}} |a_n|$$
which implies that
$$h(x)=1+\sum_{n=1}^\infty b_n \frac{x^n}{n!}\ \ \forall \ x\in \mathbb{R}$$
where $$|b_n|\le \sup_{n\in\mathbb{N}} |a_n| \ \ \forall \ n\in\mathbb{N} 
\,\,\,\,\,\& \,\,\,\,\,  \sup_{x>0}\left|h(x)\right| < \infty $$

And hence if $b_k<0$, then there exists $l>k$ such that $b_l>0$. I want to yield a contradiction by supposing this, but I failed.

Any hints or other new ideas? Thanks in advance!

(I heard that this problem can be solved by complex analysis. This is the reason why I attach the complex-analysis tag.)

Comment: Have you tried calculating $e^xf(x)$?

Comment: @Jakobian What did you mean? I tied to analyze the Maclaurin expansion of $e^x f(x)$ in my attempt. I thought that both $e^x$ and $f(x)$ have Maclaurin expansions with infinite convergence radius and hence $e^xf(x)$ has a Maclaurin expansion with infinite convergence radius.

Comment: Where is this problem from? Knowing the context might help in finding a solution.

Comment: @PhoemueX Sorry, it's from a list of problems that my tutor sent us which, form his perspective, seem not hard but actually are difficult to solve. I'm afraid this might not be helpful for finding a solution.

Comment: @Zero No, it's not helpful. It could be helpful though if you told us in which direction of maths your tutor is working and/or teaching. If this is from a course on Complex Analysis, it could also be helpful to know if this is an advanced course or a basic one and which topics have been discussed lately.

Comment: @amsmath It's a problem from my Mathematical Analysis course. The content of this course is roughly the same as that of Rudin's Principles of Mathematical Analysis. My tutor said that he didn't find an elementary solution but he can solve it via the tools in Complex Analysis. He didn't mention much about how to solve it via Complex Analysis but he inspired us to try to find an elementary solution (but I failed...). I'm afraid that what I said still won't help you find a solution. From my memory he mentioned 'Laplace transform' which I'm not familiar with.

Comment: https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2016/10/18/a-problem-involving-power-series/

Comment: @mathworker21: Great finding! The question has [already been asked](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3147563), but the answer given seems mistaken. Reading through the comments on Terrence Tao's page, I found [the link to the solution](https://works.bepress.com/iosif-pinelis/14/download/) proposed by **Iosif Pinelis**, who is [active on MSE](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/96609/iosif-pinelis) too. I have pinged him, hopefully he will answer and maybe paste here the solution from his file.

Comment: @AlexM. : Done -- thank you for letting me know.

Answer (score 6):

Let us prove the following:

> **Theorem**
>   Let $(a_0, a_1, \dots)$ be a bounded sequence in $\mathbb C$, and suppose that for the power series
>   \begin{equation*} 
> f(z) := \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n\frac{z^n}{n!}
> \end{equation*}
>   one has $f(x)=O(e^{-x})$ as $\mathbb R\ni x\to\infty$. 
>   Then $a_n = C (-1)^n$ for some $C\in\mathbb C$ and all $n=0,1,\dots$.

*Proof.*
Consider the sets 
\begin{equation*}
 S_1:=\{z\in\mathbb C\colon\Re z>-1\} \quad\text{and}\quad S_2:=\{z\in\mathbb C\colon|z|>1\}. 
\end{equation*}
Define functions $g_1\colon S_1\to\mathbb C$ and $g_2\colon S_2\to\mathbb C$ by the formulas 
\begin{equation*}
 g_1(z):=(z+1)\int_0^\infty e^{-zt}f(t)dt
\end{equation*}
for $z\in S_1$ and 
\begin{equation*}
 g_2(z):=(z+1)\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n/z^{n+1}  
\end{equation*}
for $z\in S_2$. These functions are well defined and analytic, since $f(x)=O(e^{-x})$ as $\mathbb R\ni x\to\infty$ and the $a_n$'s are bounded. Moreover, because $\int_0^\infty e^{-zx}x^ndx=n!/z^{n+1}$ for all $z\in S_0:=\{w\in\mathbb C\colon\Re w>1\}\subset S_1\cap S_2$, one has $g_1=g_2$ on $S_0$. 
So, $g_1$ and $g_2$ are the restrictions to $S_1$ and $S_2$ of an analytic function $g\colon S\to\mathbb C$, where $S:=S_1\cup S_2=\mathbb C\setminus\{-1\}$. 
Moreover, $g(u)=g_1(u)=(u+1)\int_0^\infty e^{-ut}f(t)dt=O((u+1)\int_0^\infty e^{-ut-t}dt)=O(1)$ for real $u>-1$ and $|g(z)|=|g_2(z)|=O(|z|\sum_{n=0}^\infty 1/|z|^{n+1})=O(1)$ as $|z|\to\infty$.

We shall show that $-1$ is a pole of $g$. 
Hence, by considering (say) the Laurent series for the function $g$ at the point $-1$ and recalling that $g(u)=O(1)$ for real $u>-1$, we conclude that $g$ is a complex constant, say $C$. Thus, 
\begin{equation*}
 \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n/z^{n+1}=\frac{g_2(z)}{z+1}=\frac C{z+1}=C\frac1{z(1+1/z)}
 =\sum_{n=0}^\infty C(-1)^n/z^{n+1}
\end{equation*}
for $z\in S_2$, and so, indeed $a_n = C (-1)^n$ for all $n=0,1,\dots$.

It remains to prove

> **Lemma**
>   Let $K:=
> \sup\limits_n|a_n|\vee\sup\limits_{t\ge0}|f(t)|e^t<\infty$. Take any $z\in\mathbb C$ such that $0<|z+1|<1/2$. 
>   Then 
>   \begin{equation*}
>  |g(z)|\le6K/|z+1|^2. 
> \end{equation*}
>   So, $-1$ is a pole of $g$.

*Proof.* 
Let $z$ be as in the statement of the lemma. Then $1/2\le|z|\le2$ and $x\le-1/2<0$, where
$x:=\Re z$ and $y:=\Im z$. 
Consider the following three possible cases.

**Case 1: $x=\Re z\le-1$.** Then $z\in S_2$, whence 
\begin{equation*}
 |g(z)|=|g_2(z)|\le \frac12\,K\sum_{n=0}^\infty 1/|z|^{n+1}\le\frac K{|z|-1}. 
\end{equation*}
Moreover, here 
\begin{equation*}
|z+1|^2=(|x|-1)^2+y^2\le|x|-1+y^2
\le (|x|-1)(|x|+1)+y^2=|z|^2-1\le3(|z|-1). 
\end{equation*}
So, in Case 1 
\begin{equation*}
 |g(z)|\le\frac{3K}{|z+1|^2}. 
\end{equation*}

**Case 2: $|z|\le1$.** Then $z\in S_1$, whence 
\begin{equation*}
 |g(z)|=|g_1(z)|\le \frac12\,K\int_0^\infty e^{-xt-t}dt\le\frac K{1+x}. 
\end{equation*}
Moreover, here $y^2\le1-x^2\le2(1+x)$, whence 
\begin{equation*}
|z+1|^2=(1+x)^2+y^2\le(1+x)^2+2(1+x)\le4(1+x). 
\end{equation*}
So, in Case 2 
\begin{equation*}
 |g(z)|\le\frac{4K}{|z+1|^2}. 
\end{equation*}

**Case 3: $x=\Re z>-1$ and $|z|>1$.** Then $z\in S_1\cap S_2$. 
Moreover, here
\begin{multline*}
|z+1|^2=(1+x)^2+y^2=2(1+x)+x^2+y^2-1=2(1+x)+|z|^2-1 \\ 
\le
2(1+x)+3(|z|-1)
\le[4(1+x)]\vee[6(|z|-1)]. 
\end{multline*}
So, either (i) $|z+1|^2\le6(|z|-1)$ and then we bound $|g(z)|$ as in Case 1, getting here $|g(z)|\le\frac{6K}{|z+1|^2}$ or (ii) $|z+1|^2\le4(1+x)$ and then we bound $|g(z)|$ as in Case 2, getting here $|g(z)|\le\frac{4K}{|z+1|^2}$.

Thus, the proof of the lemma is complete.

Thus, the proof of the theorem is complete.

**Remark.**
As the example of 
\begin{equation*}
f(x)=\exp\{-(a+i\sqrt{1-a^2})x\}\quad\text{or}\quad f(x)= 
\Re\exp\{-(a+i\sqrt{1-a^2})x\}  
\end{equation*}
for $a\in(0,1)$ shows, the condition $f(x)=O(e^{-x})$ in Theorem 1 cannot be relaxed to $f(x)=O(e^{-ax})$, for any real $a<1$.

Comment: Can you be more explicit as to why $g$ is constant?

Comment: @Unit : I have added the detail "and recalling that $g(u)=O(1)$ for real $u>-1$".

Answer (score 6):

There is a proof using the following [Phragmén-Lindelöf principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phragm%C3%A9n%E2%80%93Lindel%C3%B6f_principle) on a sector of the complex plane.
**Theorem:** Consider a closed sector $S=\{z\in {\mathbb C}^*\mid \alpha\leq\arg(z)\leq\beta\}\cup\{0\}$ of angular opening $\beta-\alpha<\pi$.
Consider $f:S\to\mathbb C$ continuous on $S$, holomorphic in its interior.
Suppose that $f$ is bounded by 1 on the boundary of $S$ and that there exists a constant $C$ such that $|f(z)|\leq C\exp(C|z|)$ for $z\in S$.
Then $|f(z)|\leq1$ for $z\in S$.
To show that this theorem is not a mysterious black box, I add a (classical) proof using the maximum modulus principle at the end of the answer. Actually, this proof could be incorporated in the answer to make it only use the maximum modulus principle, but I prefer to refer to the Phragmén-Lindelöf principle.

Answer to the question: Let $M>1$ denote a bound for $|a_n|$, $n\in\mathbb N$ and for $|e^xf(x)|$, $x\geq0$. Then it is readily shown that
$$|f(x)|\leq M e^{|x|}\mbox{ for }x\in\mathbb C.$$
Consider now the sector $S=S(\alpha)$ of the upper half plane bounded by the rays 
$\arg x=0$ and $\arg x=\pi-\alpha$ with some small positive $\alpha$. Consider
on $S$ the function
$$g(x)=\frac1M\exp(q(\alpha)ix)\, e^xf(x)$$
with a real positive $q(\alpha)$ to be determined. Clearly its modulus can be bounded by some expression  $\exp(C|x|)$ on $S$ if $C$ is sufficiently large. On the ray $\arg x=0$, we find that $|g(x)|\leq 1$ by the choice of $M$. On the ray
$\arg x=\alpha$, we find
$$|g(x)|\leq e^{|x|}\exp\left(\mbox{Re}\,x\right)\exp\left(-q(\alpha)\mbox{Im}\,x\right)\leq\exp(|x|(1-\cos\alpha-q(\alpha)\sin\alpha)).$$
If we choose $q(\alpha)=(1-\cos(\alpha))/\sin(\alpha)$, then we can conclude that
$|g(x)|\leq1$ also on the ray $\arg x=\pi-\alpha$.

Now the Phragmén-Lindelöf principle applies on $S$ and yields that $|g(x)|\leq1$
on $S$. This means that
$$|e^xf(x)|\leq M\exp(q(\alpha)\mbox{Im}\,x)\mbox{ for }x\in S(\alpha).$$
Let us now fix some $x$ in the upper half plane ($\mbox{Im}\,x>0$). For any sufficiently small positive $\alpha$, the sector $S(\alpha)$ contains $x$ and the above inequality holds. Observe that $M$ is independent of $\alpha$.
Now as $\alpha$ tends to 0, $q(\alpha)=(1-\cos\alpha)/\sin\alpha$ also does.
Hence we obtain that $|e^xf(x)|\leq M$ for $x$ in the upper half plane.
For $x$ on the real axis we also have $|e^xf(x)|\leq M$: For non-negative $x$ by assumption and choice of $M$, for negative $x$ because of $|f(x)|\leq Me^{|x|}$.
For $x$ in the lower half plane, we can conclude in exactly the same way, that
$|e^xf(x)|\leq M$.

Therefore $e^xf(x)$ is a bounded entire function and, by Liouville's theorem, it is a constant. Since the value at $x=0$ is 1 by assumption, we find that
$e^xf(x)=1$ and hence $f(x)=e^{-x}$. The uniqueness of the Taylor series yields $a_n=(-1)^n$.

Proof of the Theorem: Using a rotation in $\mathbb C$, we can assume that $\alpha=-\beta$. We choose $r>1$ such that $2r\beta<\pi$. For arbitrary $B>0$, we consider the function $g_B(z)=f(z)\exp\left(-B\,z^r\right)$ on $S$. Since $\mbox{Re }(z^r)\geq \gamma|z|^r$ with $\gamma=\cos(r\beta)>0$ on $S$, we find
$$|g_B(z)|\leq C\exp\left(C|z|-B\gamma\,|z|^r\right)\mbox{ on }S.$$
Therefore, if $R$ is sufficiently large, we have $|g_B(z)|\leq1$ for $z\in S$ with $|z|=R$.
Now $|g_B(z)|\leq1$ for $z$ on the boundary of $S_B=\{z\in S\mid|z|\leq R\}$. As $g_B$ is holomorphic in the interior of $S_B$, the maximum modulus principle applies and yields that $|g_B(z)|\leq1$ on $S_B$. Since $R$ can be chosen arbitrarily large, this is valid on the whole sector $S$. Thus we have proved for arbitrary $B>0$ that $|f(z)|\leq |\exp\left(B\,z^r\right)|$ on $S$.
Fixing $z$ and letting $B$ tend to 0, we obtain that $|f(z)|\leq 1 $ as desired.

Comment: Thanks! This is a really nice and short proof. I decided to award the bounty to the other answer since it was given much earlier - sorry about that.